# Type II Superstring and Open String

Tags: string-theory, branes

I would like to trow away some confusion I'm accumulating.

1. Usually when superstrings are introducted (see for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superstring_theory)) one says: Type I is a theory of open and closed strings, while Type II (A and B) is a theory of only closed strings. That is ok;
2. After some exploration ones find that one of most important object in Type II theory are Dbrane, where, by definition, open strings can end. So in Type II theory *there are* open string. As you can see at [page 53 of the PDF](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string/three.pdf#page=5), Tong affirm:

> For type II superstrings, the open strings and Dbranes
>   are necessary ingredients.

How can the apparent tension (if not contraddiction) of points 1. 2. be solved?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the idea is that there are no open strings in IIA, IIB *in perturbation theory around the vacuum*. As you say, we know D-branes exist in IIA and IIB, and these are defined as the submanifolds where open strings can end, so if a theory has D-branes it should also have open strings. But to have an open string means that you necessarily have a heavy, solitonic-like object (the D-brane), the D-brane tension goes like $T_p \propto 1/g_s$, so if $g_s \ll 1$ as it would be in perturbation theory, the D-branes are non-perturbative objects. Therefore you would not say that IIA, IIB has open strings in perturbation theory around the vacuum; they have open strings in perturbation theory around the various D-brane solutions.